Execute command before killing/stopping a docker container on windows
I want to copy the files generated inside a docker container, to the local storage before stopping/killing the container.
I am creating an docker image.
I am using docker run --name <docker_container_name> --mount type=bind,source=%cd%,target=<folder> <docker_image> <python_path> python_script.py to create and run a container.
After the python script is executed, the container will be deleted automatically.
I want at the end, before stopping/killing the container, to copy the files from inside the container to the local storage.
Do you have any ideas how can I do that?
I was thinking to use docker create and then docker start to run the container, and then to stop it after some time and to copy the files with docker cp.

Any particular reason why you aren't using the bind functionality, so the changes can be stored in the host machine? You can bind mount a folder and your results will be saved automatically.
Here is a discussion of reddit regarding the same.
Reddit

The directory from where the script is launched (batch script that runs docker commands) is actually mounted with type bind.
The files are generated in appdata/local, and this folder is not mounted with type bind.
